# PySide6 TypeError when trying to open window for second time

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside6

I have two classes in PySide6. One is the main window and the second one is a widgetWindow.
The main window is opening the widgetWindow with this function:

```
def connect_modbus(self):
    # connect with modbus 
    self.connect_modbus = ConnectModbusWindow()
    self.connect_modbus.show()
```

The ConnectModbusWindow Class looks like this:

```
class ConnectModbusWindow(QWidget, Ui_ModbusConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

I have no problem opening the ConnectModbusWindow for the first time. But when I try it for the second time i get the following error:

> TypeError: 'ConnectModbusWindow' object is not callable

It doesn't matter if I am closing the window, with the red close button or with
`self.close()`.

I created the Ui_ModbusConfig class which gets inherited by ConnectModbusWindow in the pyside6-designer.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you've done something like `ConnectModbusWindow = ConnectModbusWindow()` because the name no longer refers to the class, it refers to an instance.

Comment: I gave the class variable of ConnectModbusWindow (self.connect_modbus) the same name as the function (def connect_modbus)

Comment: That won't work. The name can only be used for one thing -- it's either a variable or a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave my variable self.connect_modbus the same name as the function itself.

```
def connect_modbus(self):
    # connect with modbus 
    self.connect_modbus = ConnectModbusWindow()
    self.connect_modbus.show()
```